# MSBuild: How can you find out where a specific file is added to _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, csproj, nuget-package-restore

When I build a specific project there is an undesired file being copied into the output from a nuget package during the `_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal` task. I can't determine from the logs or a search of project references why the file is marked CopyLocal. Is there anything logged that could help? Or is there a property or item group that I can start printing out debug messages to track it down?

#### More details:

The file is part of a Nuget package, but it isn't directly referenced in the project where the copy happens.

The project where the copy happens is part of a large complex .NET Framework application. The project has 5 `PackageReference` , and 1 `ProjectReferences`. The ProjectReference project has an additional 17 `PackageReferences` and 7 `ProjectReferences` and the tree keeps going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet will generate `obj\...nuget.g.props`/`.targets` file that contains the reference.
This can be controlled via [Dependency asset attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets) - e.g. setting `ExcludeAssets="contentfiles"` on the `PackageReference`.

Using a binary log (adding `-bl` to msbuild/`dotnet build` invocations) and opening it in the [structured log viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/) gives you good search options in the logical build tree and the files / log output which can help find these files.